# How to define manifest "Requirements" to require Excel API 1.3 and Word API 1.3 (in a single manifest)

Tags: office-js, office-store

My Add-In (runs in Excel 1.3 & Word 1.3) was rejected by the Office Store because I can't see how to define this in this manifest "Requirements".
I have a single Office.js add-in that needs to run in both Excel and Word at the same time (it integrates the 2).  It requires API 1.3 of both Word and Excel (won't work in 2013).  I cannot figure out how to require 2016 versions in the manifest.

This is not valid (requires a 'set' in 'sets'):

```
<Requirements>
   <Sets DefaultMinVersion="1.3">
   </Sets>
</Requirements>
```

I do not see a 'set' with MinVersion="1.3" that is common to Excel and Word.

I do not see any "Methods" that are in common with Excel and Word (requiring 1.3).  For example 'Method Name="Document.getSelectedDataAsync"' only is valid with Word.

Here is what I've done:
In the add-in public description, I clearly indicate that it requires specific versions of Office 2016 (or newer).
I use runtime checks (isSetSupported) and if the user does not have Word or Excel that supports API 1.3, I provide a clear notification telling them their version is not compatible and what versions are.  I also disable all features (so there are no errors).

The "Validation Test Results" report indicate I must indicate 2016 requirements in the manifest.  It says:
"If you do not support 2013 SP1 because you are using an API only available in 2016/Online, you must put these apis in the requirements tag in your manifest. If you are not using an API only available in 2016/Online, then you must support 2013 SP1. "

But how can I define this requirement (1.3 for both Excel and Word) in the manifest?

Comment: Excellent question. I'm doing a bit of research to get you proper guidance for submitting an add-in like this and will get back to you ASAP.

Comment: Michael Z told me that there is no manifest-based solution yet (Microsoft is working on it).  The solution is to re-submit and explain the above limitation in the testing notes.  I have re-submitted and await a response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you've resubmitted and explained the issue in the test notes, the validation team will reachout to you at the email address on record to discuss how to proceed in this scenario.

Comment: I did explain this in the testing notes.  The validation team was able to manually restrict requirements to Office 2016 and Online and the add-in was approved: https://store.office.com/app.aspx?assetid=WA104380892